# Remove array object inside array

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

In a Redux's reducer I need to decrement the quantity of the item inside the cart array if the quantity of the item is greater than 1. If that is exactly 1 the entire object should be filtered out from that array. How to achieve this?

### Reducer.js

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  cart: []
};

const shopReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, { type, payload }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case "SUB_QUANTITY":
      console.log("Cart", state.cart)
      return {
        ...state,
        cart: state.cart.map((product) => product.id === payload ? 
          { ...product, count: product.count - 1 } : { ...product })
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

The code above will be decrement the count to 0,-1,-2. I try for `product.count===1 ? filter(......) : the code mentioned in the reducer`. But it gives an empty array inside cart array if the count=1. How can I use filter method inside map method?

Answer (score 0):

Check the code below. I decrement the correct item's count first, then filter it out if the count is less than 1.

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  cart: []
};

const shopReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, { type, payload }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case "SUB_QUANTITY":
      console.log("Cart", state.cart)
      // reduce the quantity
      const updated = state.cart.map((product) => { 
          if(product.id === payload) {
              product.count = product.count - 1
          }
      })
      // return items that have count higher than 0
      const filtered = updated.filter((product) => (
          product.count > 0
      ))
      return {
        ...state,
        cart: filtered
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by conditional rendering in the front end. For count 0 I call removecart() else I call subQuantity()

```
const handleDecrement = () => {
      cart.map((product: any) => product.id === item.id &&
        product.count > 1 ? subQuantity(item.id) : removeFromCart(item.id))
    }
```